# Date picking a date out of a php calender

Tags: php, date, datepicker

We are having a problem with our PHP Calender: We want to pick a certain date, f.e. 15th of December 2016, and change the background color for a start!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php
    $date = time();
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");

    $day = date('d', $date);
    $month = date('m', $date);
    $year = date('y', $date);

    $first_day = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
    $title = date('F', $first_day);
    $day_of_week = date('D', $first_day);

    switch ($day_of_week){
        case "Mon": $blank = 0; break;
        case "Tue": $blank = 1; break;
        case "Wed": $blank = 2; break;
        case "Thu": $blank = 3; break;
        case "Fri": $blank = 4; break;
        case "Sat": $blank = 5; break;
        case "Sun": $blank = 6; break;
    }

    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

    echo "<table border=6 width=394>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan=60> $title $year </th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td width=62>Monday</td><td width=62>Tuesday</td><td width=62>Wednesday</td><td width=62>Thursday</td><td width=62>Friday</td><td width=62>Saturday</td><td width=62>Sunday</td></tr>";

    $day_count = 1;

    echo "<tr>";

    while ($blank > 0 ) {
        echo "<td></td>";
        $blank = $blank-1;
        $day_count++;
    }

    $day_num = 1;

    // Deze while-loop zorgt ervoor dat de tabel naar de volgende rij gaat na 7 dagen.
    while ($day_num <= $days_in_month) {
        echo "<td>$day_num</td>"; // if statement hier in zetten om achtergrond te veranderen
        $day_num++;
        $day_count++;          

        if  ($day_count > 7){
            echo "<tr></tr>";
            $day_count = 1;
        }
    }

    while ($day_count > 1 && $day_count <= 7){
        echo "<td> </td>";
        $day_count++;
    }

    echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: There is no code ;)

Comment: Looks like you forget to post the code...

Comment: Sorry, had to add it an other way :)

Comment: Can't you put it as code and no as image ?

Comment: Need 10 reputation :(

Comment: To add text ? No you can do it without any reputation, just copy / paste the code instead of the image

Comment: Hehe, there we go!

Comment: Where is your `cal_days_in_month` function ?

Comment: This is for the amount of days that are present in a month, For example 31 days in March and 30 in April

Comment: I asked to my teacher how we should fix it, and he recommended an If-statement in the echo "<td>$day_num</td>";

Comment: If you know the number of the day you can do it. Check if it match with `$day_num` change the color

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($day_num == '15'){$bg = "style='background-color:red'";}else{$bg="";}
```

if you want matching with today day

```
    if($day_num == $day){$bg = "style='background-color:red'";}else{$bg="";}
```

Put it here

while ($day_num <= $days_in_month) {

```
    if($day_num == $day){$bg = "style='background-color:red'";}else{$bg="";}




   echo "<td $bg>$day_num</td>"; // if statement hier in zetten om achtergrond te veranderen
    $day_num++;
    $day_count++;          


    if  ($day_count > 7){
        echo "<tr></tr>";
        $day_count = 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: It didn't work, and I think its because the calender is generated with a while-loop and the system doesn't find the number :(

Comment: where do you put it ?